# How do you call a second "external" function using Nodejs, Expressjs and bluebird

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bluebird

Im working on building a nodejs (which I'm pretty new to) application.  I've figured out using Promises and am able to pull data in from a database.  you can see the code I'm working with here:

myModel.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var mysql = require('../helpers/db');

// handle a get request
exports.post = function(params, callback) 
{
    function getData() 
    {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) 
        {
            mysql.getResults('select id from someTable',function(err, rows) 
            {
                resolve(rows);
            });
        });
    }

    function getMoreData() 
    {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) 
        {
            mysql.getResults('select * from anotherTable',function(err, rows) 
            {
                resolve(rows);
            });
        });
    }

    getData().then(
        function(data)
        {
            console.log(data); // Log the value once it is resolved
            return data;
        })
    ).then(
        function(d)
        {
            console.log(d);
        }
    ).catch(
        function(err) 
        {
            console.log(err)
        }
    );
}
```

../helpers/db.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    database : 'XXXXXX',
    port     : 3306,
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'XXXXXX',
    password : 'XXXXXX'
});

var executeQuery = Promise.promisify(function executeQuery(query, callback) {
    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err, null);
        }
        else if (connection) {
            connection.query(query, function (err, rows, fields) {
                connection.release();
                if (err) {
                    return callback(err, null);
                }
                return callback(null, rows);
            })
        }
        else {
            return callback("No connection", null);
        }
    });
})
var getResults = Promise.promisify(function getResult(query,callback) {
  executeQuery(query, function (err, rows) {
     if (!err) {
        callback(null,rows);
     }
     else {
        callback(true,err);
     }
   });
})

exports.getResults = getResults;
```

This all works fine.  Now what if I want to also pull it data from the function getMoreData?  The goal is be to use data from getData to use in querying the data in getMoreData, and the push the results farther down the "then" chain.

Just having trouble getting my brain around how that would happen.....and I've been banging my head on this all day....

Help is appreciated.

***** EDIT *****

Here's what I have found to work:

myModel.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var mysql = require('../helpers/db');

// handle a get request
exports.post = function(params, callback) 
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
    {
        mysql.getResults('select id from sometable order by id', function(err, rows1) 
        {
            // console.log(rows1[0]);
            mysql.getResults('select field1, field2 from someothertable where id=' + rows1[0].id, function(err, rows2) 
            {
                resolve(rows2);
            });
        })
    }).then(function (params) 
    {
        callback(null, params);
    });
}
```

../helpers/db.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    database : 'XXXXX',
    port     : 3306,
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'XXXXX',
    password : 'XXXXX'
});

var executeQuery = function executeQuery(query, callback) {
    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err, null);
        }
        else if (connection) {
            connection.query(query, function (err, rows, fields) {
                connection.release();
                if (err) {
                    return callback(err, null);
                }
                return callback(null, rows);
            })
        }
        else {
            return callback("No connection", null);
        }
    });
}
var getResults = function getResult(query,callback) 
{
    executeQuery(query, function (err, rows) 
    {
        if (!err) 
        {
            callback(null,rows);
        }
        else 
        {
            callback(true,err);
        }
    });
}

exports.getResults = getResults;
```

Accepted the answer because it got me 90% of the way there.  Using the added promise was the only way to get the second getResults to resolve.  Then I removed the promises from helpers/db, which alleviates the anti-pattern issue.

Comment: So are you saying you want to use the result from the first query as a parameter for the second query? Because if you are, then you need to nest the calls. So, don't resolve the first query (resolve(rows); in getData(). Instead do return getMoreData(parameters); As it's a promise that resolves then it should work out OK.

Comment: Also, as you are returning a promise from getResults, you don't need to create a new one in getData; https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So are you saying you want to use the result from the first query as a parameter for the second query? Because if you are, then you need to nest the calls. So, don't resolve the first query. As it's a promise that resolves then it should work out OK.

Something like this might be what you want

```
    exports.post = function (params, callback) {
       mysql.getResults('select id from someTable', function (err, rows1) {
        mysql.getResults('select * from anotherTable', function (err, rows2) {
          resolve(rows2);
        });
      }).then(function (params, etc) {
        console.log(params);
      });
    }
```

EDIT: I've actually looked at this and here is a solution using only a single promise:

helpers/db.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    database : 'XX',
    port     : 3306,
    host     : 'XX',
    user     : 'XX',
    password : 'XX'
});

var executeQuery = function (query, callback) {
pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    if (err) {
        return callback(err, null);
    }
    else if (connection) {
        connection.query(query, function (err, rows, fields) {
            connection.release();
            if (err) {
                return callback(err, null);
            }
            return callback(null, rows);
        })
    }
    else {
        return callback("No connection", null);
    }
});
}
var getResults = function (query,callback) {
    return executeQuery(query, function (err, rows) {
        if (!err) {
            callback(null,rows);
        }
        else {
            callback(true,err);
        }
    });
}

exports.getResults = getResults;
```

myModel.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var mysql = require('../helpers/db');

// handle a get request
exports.post =  function (params, callback) {
    function getData(){
        return new Promise(function (resolve,reject){
            mysql.getResults('select username from user', function (err, rows1) {
                mysql.getResults("select * from user where username = '" + rows1[0].username + "'", function (err, rows2) {
                    resolve(rows2);
                })
            });
        });
    }

    getData()
    .then(function (params, etc) {
        console.log('params',params);
    });

}
```

EDIT 2: I just noticed you've updated your question to show the answer - Identical to mine. So +1 for that.

Comment: Gives me a "resolve is not defined" error.  However I can use query one as a parameter of query two now, so thats progress.  Because getResults is a promise, I don't understand why it can't be resolved.

Comment: Here is what is working:
`
exports.post = function(params, callback) 
{
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
 {
  mysql.getResults('select id from sometable order by id', function(err, rows1) 
  {
   // console.log(rows1[0]);
   mysql.getResults('select field1, field2 from someothertable where id=' + rows1[0].id, function(err, rows2) 
   {
    resolve(rows2);
   });
  })
 }).then(function (params) 
 {
  callback(null, params);
 });

`

Along with this, I did a promisifyAll on helpers/db.js

Comment: You only actually need a single promise in the whole thing - so it could be refactored to reflect that. However as it's working, you can move forward. Have a look at the promise anti pattern link in my comment on your question and see if you can see why that is. It was a revelation to me when I realised I'd been doing it wrong!

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to do it with only 1 promise in the system